# Xamarin Java Library Binding issues

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.android, java-binding

I want to use `agency tango materialintroscreen` library in my `Xamarin.Android` project.

I have created a Xamarin Android Binding Project, copy the `ARR` file in the `Jars Folder` and set Build Action to `LibraryProjectZip`.

Then I reference the project in my main Xamarin.Android project. 
Normally I can access to `agency.tango.materialintroscreen` but have the error the namespace doesn't exist.

I try to use `jetBrains dotpeek` I saw `dll` was create well with all class.
I have the same error with 3 library
[Visual Studio Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8kq9.png)

[Object Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkjcs.png)

Comment: Going to need details of what your actual problem is.

Comment: Sounds like you might have duplicate references to support library in your project.

Comment: I juste resolve that problem when change the target Framework

Comment: Just update my Jdk 8 to latest version and problem slove...Thanks